# Change CancelButtonText of QInputDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to overwrite/change the text of the Cancel button of a QInputDialog that I use for a password input.
I tried the following, but the new text does not show up during the `getText`. The logging shows that the new text was saved inside.

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```py
caption_cancel = 'Cancel and go to previous mode'

input_password_dialog = QtWidgets.QInputDialog(self)
input_password_dialog.setInputMode(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.TextInput)
input_password_dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.UsePlainTextEditForTextInput)

logging.debug('cancelButtonText = ' + input_password_dialog.cancelButtonText())  # 'Cancel'

input_password_dialog.setCancelButtonText(caption_cancel)

logging.debug('cancelButtonText = ' + input_password_dialog.cancelButtonText())  # 'Cancel and go to previous mode'

password, ok = input_password_dialog.getText(self, 'Authentification', 'Password',
                                             echo=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)  # just shows 'Cancel"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- `QInputDialog::getText()` is a static method so it will not use the `input_password_dialog` object, so you must directly set the properties such as the title, label, etc. to the `input_password_dialog` object, or try to apply a hack to get the QInputDialog created in the static method .
- If you set `QInputDialog.TextInput` and `QInputDialog.UsePlainTextEditForTextInput` then the dots will not be displayed instead of text as a password entry.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
caption_cancel = "Cancel and go to previous mode"

input_password_dialog = QtWidgets.QInputDialog(self)
# input_password_dialog.setInputMode(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.TextInput)
# input_password_dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.UsePlainTextEditForTextInput)
input_password_dialog.setCancelButtonText(caption_cancel)
input_password_dialog.setWindowTitle("Authentification")
input_password_dialog.setLabelText("Password")
input_password_dialog.setTextEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

if input_password_dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
    password = input_password_dialog.textValue()
    print(password)
```

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly :-)